# How to handle null data from SQL Server 2017 in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, left-join, join

I want to display two joined tables from my SQL Server 2017 using C#. I followed [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MLhffhKrmQ). When everything seemed so perfectly fine, I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I found out it was because of the null I set in my table.

I knew I could use the `LEFT JOIN` to handle the null values. But the problem is I don't know how to include the SQL command in my C# file.

The highlighted error line is : `<td>@item.rule.Amount</td>`

The suspected part I think I did wrong is

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    db1 sd = new db1();

    List<Group> groups = sd.Groups.ToList();
    List<Rule> rule = sd.Rules.ToList();
    List<RuleDesc> ruleDesc = sd.RuleDescs.ToList();

    ViewData["jointtables"] = from g in groups
                              join r in rule on g.AcctNo equals r.AcctNo 
                              into table1
                              from r in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new Class1 { groups = g, rule = r};

    return View(ViewData["joinedtables"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assume the null field is mynull then it should be:

```
bool isnull = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("mynull"))
```

or you can use COALESCE() or IFNULL() in your SQL Query

Comment: Where should I put the statement at?

Answer (score 0):

When displaying values in views in ASP.NET or .NET Core using **Razor View Engine**, I suggest you to use methods like .GetValueOrDefault() on `nullable` types.

Let say, if your `Amount` field in your model is the type of: `int?` `double?` or `float?` then use `GetValueOrDefault()` method.

For example:

```
<td>@item.rule.Amount.GetValueOrDefault()</td>
```

This will avoid the error page showing `System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

I hope this helps.

Comment: But my field is string type. So what should I put?

Comment: Try debugging then, and look for the object `rule` inside `item`, as well at their properties. See if you can somehow initialize the values of those properties.

Comment: thanks to @marc_s whom edited my code. So I replaced the `return View(ViewData["jointtables"])` to `return View(ViewData["joinedtables"]);` . Then when I ran it, it worked. Thanks!